# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1,Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the query error is pointing at, don't know what's wrong?

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(a.classes),0) 
from (SELECT DISTINCT a.for_date, COUNT(DISTINCT classID) as classes 
      FROM School_Classes sc 
      INNER JOIN app_attendance a on a.schoolclass_id = sc.Id 
      WHERE schoolID =@SchoolID AND a.for_date BETWEEN 
      DATEADD(DAY,-30,getdate()) AND getdate() GROUP BY a.for_date
      ) a
```

Comment: Well, the error message is `subquery returned more than 1 value`. You have two subqueries in your question. Please [edit] your question with relevant example data and also check which of the two subqueries returns more than one value.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read and to understand.

Comment: The error is actually telling you the problem here. I'm sure, if you were to run the query in the parenthesis (`()`) you would have multiple rows returned. Considering your setting the value of a **scalar** variable, how are you expecting it to hold the value of multiple rows? (Hint: it can't). You need to have your query return one row. We don;t know your data though, so that's as much as we can help you with.

Comment: You have 3 subqueries here. Only one of them matches the *rest of the error message* however, which you've chosen to ignore/not include here. The ones after `FROM` and `IN` don't match the error.

Comment: classID is an integer and for_date is datetime.

Comment: The SQL you've edited to won't return that error... A subquery in a `FROM` ***can*** return multiple rows. The problem was when you were using `SET`.

Comment: @Larnu actually i am using cursor to iterate through the list of schools. If a go one on one with the list of schools there is no error even in setting the scalar variable value because the SUM() function will always return single row. But while executing the stored procedure there is this error. Don't know what to do?

Comment: Why are you using a cursor to do such a task in  the first place. Iterative tasks one of the worst things that SQL Server does; its forté is set based operations. I think there's a far bigger problem than what you're letting on here. I think it's about time we saw your **full** sql statement (cursor and all) and some sample data (in the form of DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements) and expected results for the sample.

Answer (score 0):

The stored Procedure is as follow:

```
USE [smsdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DailyAlertGSP]    Script Date: 28/11/2018 2:47:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DailyAlertGSP] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @RegionIn varchar(150),
    @isArea bit
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sumAgeing int,@countAgeing int,@sumTotalClasses int,@sumClassesAttendance int,@sumStudentStrength int
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @SchoolID INT ,@principalID VARCHAR(50),@ageing INT,@totalClasses INT,@classesAttendance INT,@percentage FLOAT,@ssr INT,@noDays INT
    DECLARE @region varchar(150),@area VARCHAR(150),@schoolName VARCHAR(150),@principalName VARCHAR(150)
    DECLARE @StartDate date,@EndDate date
DECLARE @FinalData TABLE (Region VARCHAR(150), Area VARCHAR(150), [School ID] INT, [School Name] VARCHAR(150), [Principal Code] INT, [Principal Name] VARCHAR(150),
Ageing INT, [Total Classes] INT, [Classes Attendance] INT, [Precentage (%)] FLOAT, [Student Strength] INT) 

iF @isArea = 1 
    DECLARE AllSchools CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT s.schoolID as school FROM dbo.Region r INNER JOIN dbo.Area a ON r.regionID = a.regionID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Location l ON a.areaID = l.areaID INNER JOIN Campus c on c.locationid = l.locationid INNER JOIN School s on s.campusID = c.id
    --INNER JOIN SchoolEMIS se ON s.schoolID=se.schoolID 
    WHERE a.Name like @RegionIn AND s.isDeleted = 0 order by r.Name;
ELSE 
    DECLARE AllSchools CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT s.schoolID as school FROM dbo.Region r INNER JOIN dbo.Area a ON r.regionID = a.regionID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Location l ON a.areaID = l.areaID INNER JOIN Campus c on c.locationid = l.locationid INNER JOIN School s on s.campusID = c.id 
    --INNER JOIN SchoolEMIS se ON s.schoolID=se.schoolID
    WHERE r.Name like @RegionIn AND s.isDeleted = 0 order by r.Name;

OPEN AllSchools
FETCH NEXT FROM AllSchools INTO @SchoolID


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    SET @StartDate = GETDATE(); SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY,-30,getdate())
    SET @schoolName = (SELECT Name FROM School WHERE schoolID=@SchoolID)
    IF @isArea = 1
    SET @region = (Select r.Name FROM dbo.Region r INNER JOIN dbo.Area a ON r.regionID = a.regionID 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.Location l ON a.areaID = l.areaID INNER JOIN Campus c on c.locationid = l.locationid INNER JOIN School s on s.campusID = c.id 
                   WHERE a.Name like @RegionIn AND s.schoolID = @SchoolID )
    ELSE
    SET @region = (Select r.Name FROM dbo.Region r INNER JOIN dbo.Area a ON r.regionID = a.regionID 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.Location l ON a.areaID = l.areaID INNER JOIN Campus c on c.locationid = l.locationid INNER JOIN School s on s.campusID = c.id 
                   WHERE r.Name like @RegionIn AND s.schoolID = @SchoolID )
    IF @isArea = 1
    SET @area = (Select a.Name FROM dbo.Region r INNER JOIN dbo.Area a ON r.regionID = a.regionID 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.Location l ON a.areaID = l.areaID INNER JOIN Campus c on c.locationid = l.locationid INNER JOIN School s on s.campusID = c.id 
                 WHERE a.Name like @RegionIn AND s.schoolID = @SchoolID )
    ELSE
    SET @area = (Select a.Name FROM dbo.Region r INNER JOIN dbo.Area a ON r.regionID = a.regionID 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.Location l ON a.areaID = l.areaID INNER JOIN Campus c on c.locationid = l.locationid INNER JOIN School s on s.campusID = c.id 
                 WHERE r.Name like @RegionIn AND s.schoolID = @SchoolID )
    SET @principalID = (SELECT [Employee Code] FROM [hcmdbserv].[HCM_LIVE].[dbo].[vw_BI_Principal_Info] WHERE [Job Status] = 'Active' AND [End Date_H] is NULL 
                        AND [School ID_K] = @SchoolID)
    SET @principalName = (SELECT ISNULL(First_Name,'') +' '+ISNULL(Name,'') FROM [hcmdbserv].[HCM_LIVE].[dbo].[vw_BI_Principal_Info] WHERE [Job Status] = 'Active' AND [End Date_H] is NULL 
                          AND [School ID_K] = @SchoolID)
    SET @ageing = (SELECT (SELECT DateDiff(DAY,(SELECT MAX([TimeStamp]) as LastDate),getdate())) FROM app_AuditLog WHERE InFunction ='StudentDataController.Get' AND OnTask = 'School'  AND ObjectData = @SchoolID) 
    SET @ssr = (select top 1 totalStrength from Academics_Master where schoolId = @SchoolID order by id desc)
    SET @noDays = (SELECT dbo.ufn_GetWeekDays(@EndDate,@StartDate))
    SET @totalClasses = ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM School_Classes WHERE schoolID=@SchoolID)*@noDays)
    SET @classesAttendance = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(a.classes),0) from (SELECT DISTINCT a.for_date, COUNT(DISTINCT classID) as classes FROM School_Classes sc 
                                INNER JOIN app_attendance a on a.schoolclass_id = sc.Id WHERE schoolID =@SchoolID AND a.for_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30,getdate()) 
                                AND getdate() GROUP BY a.for_date) a)
    if (@classesAttendance = 0) BEGIN SET @percentage = 0 END
    ELSE BEGIN SET @percentage = (@classesAttendance *100.0 /@totalClasses) END
    IF (@principalID is NULL) BEGIN SET @principalID = '' END
    IF (@principalName is NULL) BEGIN SET @principalName = '' END
    IF (@ageing IS NULL) BEGIN SET @ageing = 0 END
    IF (@totalClasses IS NULL) BEGIN SET @totalClasses = 0 END
    IF (@classesAttendance IS NULL) BEGIN SET @classesAttendance = 0 END
    IF (@percentage IS NULL) BEGIN SET @percentage = 0 END
    IF (@ssr IS NULL) BEGIN SET @ssr = 0 END



    INSERT INTO @FinalData (Region,Area,[School ID],[School Name],[Principal Code],[Principal Name],Ageing,[Student Strength],[Classes Attendance],[Total Classes],[Precentage (%)])
    VALUES (@region,@area,@SchoolID,@schoolName,@principalID,@principalName,@ageing,@ssr,@classesAttendance,@totalClasses,@percentage)

    FETCH NEXT FROM AllSchools INTO @SchoolID
END 

CLOSE AllSchools
DEALLOCATE AllSchools


SELECT * FROM @FinalData fd order by fd.[Precentage (%)] asc, fd.Ageing desc,fd.Area asc,fd.Region 
SET @sumTotalClasses= (SELECT SUM([Total Classes]) FROM @FinalData)
SET @sumAgeing= (SELECT SUM(Ageing) FROM @FinalData)
SET @countAgeing = (SELECT COUNT(Ageing) FROM @FinalData)
SET @sumClassesAttendance= (SELECT SUM([Classes Attendance]) FROM @FinalData)
SET @sumStudentStrength= (SELECT SUM([Student Strength]) FROM @FinalData)
--SET @averagePercentage= (SELECT CAST( (SUM([Classes Attendance])/SUM([Total Classes]) * 100) as FLOAT) FROM @FinalData)
SELECT @sumAgeing as [Sum Ageing],@countAgeing as [Count Ageing],@sumClassesAttendance as [Sum Classes],@sumStudentStrength as [Sum Student],
@sumTotalClasses as [Sum Total]
END
```

Comment: You should edit that into the question rather than posting it as an answer. But I'm not sure this is useful: it gives us some context, but really the issue is just with a query that's parameterised by @SchoolID. It would be more useful to see some example output of the whole query for a given school that's causing you problems, and some example output of the subqueries within that query if the whole query isn't enough to solve this issue.